# create cron job on windows server that executes a web url every 30 seconds

Tags: asp.net, cron

Since we have to do some cleanup on our sessions created on server. Basically we want to check every 30 seconds and log out expired sessions.

I searched few places and people referring to scheduled task but minimum time is 5 minutes there.

Some suggested to create web service. Can anyone help me to create web service in asp.net for the same.

thanks in advance.

Comment: How are the sessions stored? If it's in a sql server, you can setup a SQL job to run every 5 minutes to do whatever sql you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a so called 'long running task' and start it in Global.asax. In this Task you can create a timer to call your session-check-method every 30 seconds.

Resources for long running tasks:
- http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20051223.asp